# How to replace characters at the beginning and end of a string, but not in the middle

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm stumped on this one, although I'm sure there is probably an easy solution that I'm overlooking.

Say that I have three strings:

++JA+1

+UTM++

+G+SA+

I want to remove any +'s at the beginning and end of the strings, but I want to keep any +'s WITHIN the string. So my parsed strings would then be:

JA+1

UTM

G+SA

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var reg:RegExp = /(^\++)|(\++$)/g;

trace(("++JA+1").replace(reg, ""));
trace("+UTM++".replace(reg, ""));
trace("+G+SA+".replace(reg, ""));
```

Comment: Thank you, Pan! I figured RegExp was the way to go but couldn't quite work it out. This makes my project a lot easier! I was about to resort to a loop!

Comment: I am glad it help.If the string isn't very long, RegExp is good for this. Or you may use loop for better performance.